# Do AWS public facing Load Balancer IPs change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am creating a backend with ECS and I need to have a static IP, for what I understand from the AWS console all internet-facing load balancers are assigned an IP address by AWS, my question is: Will that IP address change? And if I have 2 Availability Zones, both have different IPs?

```
For internet-facing load balancers, the IPv4 addresses of the nodes are assigned by AWS.
For internal load balancers, the IPv4 addresses are assigned from the subnet CIDR.
```

[image]

Comment: They're not assigned "an IP address". Classic and Application Load Balancers have a DNS name. That DNS name resolves to, potentially, multiple IP addresses. Those IP addresses may change over time, in both the IPs themselves and in the number of IPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the IPs change sporadically and you're correct that the IP is different in each Availability Zone.

If you need to have static IPs, you could consider fronting an Application Load Balancer with a Network Load Balancer. This would allow an elastic IP to be set for each AZ that the NLB resides and you should still get the benefits of the ALB.

The downsides would be extra cost and latency. I haven't tried this myself so can't vouch for how well it works.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/application-load-balancer-type-target-group-for-network-load-balancer/

Answer (score 2):

> Will that IP address change? And if I have 2 Availability Zones, both have different IPs?

Yes, for application load balancer (ALB), the IPs are not static. If you want static IP for ALB you can add [AWS Global Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/what-is-global-accelerator.html) to it.

Alternatively, use network LB (NLB), which has static IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Network Load Balancer, there is the option to allocate an Elastic IP address per AZ from one of the EIPs available to you. If you don't allocate an EIP, AWS assigns a Static IP per AZ that can be used by applications as the front-end IP of the load balancer. Note that this only applies to the NLB.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/network-load-balancer/